# Rails4: Save object with has_many fails on the has_many model validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I'm trying to save two models (one to many) in one time. My code looks like this:

```
@submission = Submission.new(submission_params)

@submission_asset = @submission.attachments.new(submission_asset_params)
@submission_asset.attachment_type = 'submission_asset'

if @submission.save
  # render or redirect here
else
  @submission.errors
end
```

But when I run this I get this error `@messages={:attachments=>["is invalid"]}`. I think it's because my attachment model has this:

```
# Attachment model snippet
validates :attachable_id, :attachable_type, presence: true
```

But it's to ensure it is attached to a `Submission`. But when I remove or comment out the validation it works and saves the two models and the association.

How do I make this save?

**EDIT**

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  validates :attachable_id, :attachable_type, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Is this a polymorphic association? Could you please provide the relevant model code for your associations...

Comment: Yes it is. Added the models related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@submission_asset = @submission.attachments.build(submission_asset_params)
```

UPDATE:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, inverse_of: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  validates :attachable, presence: true
end
```

Comment: I did this but it doesn't save the attachments when I do `@submission.save`.

Comment: Actually, it still runs the validation on `Attachment` and still fails even with `build`

Comment: I'm sorry. `build` not working b/c `@submission` not persisted. Try my updates

Comment: Oh it did work after I changed from `validates :attachable_id, :attachable_type, presence: true` to `validates :attachable, presence: true`... I guess I was using the wrong fields to validate?